# AppletViewer - "applet not initialized"

Tags: java, applet, awt, paint, appletviewer

My code compiles and works just fine in both my browser and Eclipse, but for some reason the AppletViewer just won't work with my VERY simple code.  When I try to run it with `appletviewer FirstApplet.html`, the AppletViewer window appears as expected, but the upper-left part of the window just says "Applet" and the bottom-left part of the window says "Start: applet not initialized"

What could be the problem here? (Again, it works in my browser and Eclipse)

Thank you for any help! :)

---

**FirstApplet.java**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;

public class FirstApplet extends Applet {
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.drawString("This is my first Java Applet!", 20, 30);
    }
}
```

---

**FirstApplet.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>FirstApplet</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <applet
            codebase    = "."
            code        = "FirstApplet.class"
            name        = "FirstApplet"
            width       = "640"
            height      = "480"
            hspace      = "0"
            vspace      = "0"
            align       = "middle"
        >

        </applet>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: FirstApplet.html and FirstApplet.java - Are they on the same directory ?

Comment: @Bingo Yes, they are.  And I've also compiled FirstApplet.Java so there's a FirstAPplet.class file in the same folder as well.

Comment: 1) there miss some code for visibily of Applet on the screen 2) use JApplet, 3) put there JPanel and custom painting in Swing is done by using  paintComponent

Comment: @Rick_Sch I still doubt that html and class file are not on the same folder as I checked your prog and it works fine check out : http://i39.tinypic.com/ojpjiv.png

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) Why AWT rather than Swing?  See this answer on [Swing extras over AWT](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6255978/418556) for many good reasons to abandon using AWT components.  If you need to support older AWT based APIs, see [Mixing Heavyweight and Lightweight Components](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/mixing-components-433992.html).

Comment: @Bingo They are definitely in the same folder along with the other standard Eclipse mess.  http://s23.postimg.org/c7rmn69aj/First_Applet.jpg

Comment: @AndrewThompson This is not from a teach, but from a 5 year old book called Beginning Java Programming.  If what I'm doing is incorrect, it's because I don't know any better and I'm just doing what the book tells me.  Is there a better way to embed Java programs into a website these days?  Also, thanks for the Swing vs. AWT suggestion! :)

Comment: *"This is not from a teach, but from a 5 year old book"*  That book is not something you should be learning from.  Swing was introduced at least *5 years* before that, and a book teaching AWT at that stage is ..unforgivable.  Use the [Swing tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) (or a more recent book).

Comment: You're welcome.  Please drop dealing with both AWT & applets for the moment, and start with Swing based `JFrame` applications.  Not only am I much more willing to help with them, but me, and other people willing to help, can actually *remember* enough details about Swing to *provide* useful tips.  Later move on to the Swing based `JApplet`.  But *only* if you need an app. embedded in a web page.  That turns out to be very, *very*, ***very*** rarely.

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out!  It was an Eclipse problem after all!

I wrote and compiled the code in Eclipse. Eclipse's internal version of the AppletViewer worked just fine, and it worked just fine to open the HTML file that I made in my browsers.

The applet didn't work in the actual AppletViewer, however, until I compiled the code using something other than Eclipse.  It appears that for some reason AppletViewer didn't like the `.class` file that Eclipse generated.

Mystery solved!

Answer (score -1):

I was experiencing the same problem.

First of all I had removed public from my class.That lead fine compilation but no initialization in applet:(.

Next I changed it public and the code threw an error to me.

To solve error I renamed my source code as per my public class name
then I simply ran the code through appletviewer which executed all fine.

I apologize for Inconvenient explanation though.
Here are the Snippets of three Stage of my problem Solving

[Stage 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URFUi.png)

[Stage 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tp2jE.png)

[Solution Stage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HJVF.png)

I have tried to demonstrate the aspect of code changes as well :) and the RHS pane is the code webpage.

Simply keep the name of class and main class containing Source same.

Comment: Hmm , I apologize for inconvenience I will try my best to discontinue the same :)